# Passing multidimensional array from R to Fortran using Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, fortran, rcpp

I'm new to C++ and the usage of Rcpp in R. I have many Fortran subroutines that I would like to include in an R package. I have followed this [example](https://gist.github.com/jbuonagurio/b1b9da738b57081567a80aadc8adef3b#file-rcppdotprod-cpp), and it works perfectly. Now, I would like to implement one of my subroutines, a dummy Fortran subroutine saved in the file **mytest.f90**, and it looks like this:

```
module mytest
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_int

    implicit none

    public :: mytest_f

contains

    subroutine mytest_f(l, m, n, a, c) bind(C)

    integer(kind=c_int) :: l, m, n
    integer(kind=c_int) :: a(l, m, n), c(l,m,n)
    c = c - a
    end subroutine mytest_f
end module mytest
```

The Rcpp code and the C-wrapper are saved in one file called **Rcppmytest.cpp** and it contains:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

//C wrapper ??
extern "C" {
  void mytest_f(int l, int m, int n, int a, int c);
}

// Rcpp
int c_mytest_f(Rcpp::IntegerVector a3D) {

  // receives the 3D array
  Rcpp::IntegerVector DIM = a3D.attr("dim");

  int l, m, n;
  l = DIM[0];
  m = DIM[1];
  n = DIM[2];

  int c[l][m][n];

  mytest_f(l, m, n, a3D, c);

  return c;
}
```

However, I have two errors in the IDE (i.e. Rstudio). Firstly, in line `mytest_f(l, m, n, a, c);`, and the error is

> not matching function for call  to "mytest_f"

While the second error is:

> Error: Cannot initialize return object of type "int *" with an lvalue of type 'int [a_size]'

When I try to get more info from the compilation process using devtools::document() in R, this error message appears:

```
   Rcppmytest.cpp:n function ‘int c_mytest_f(Rcpp::IntegerVector)
   Rcppmytest.cpp:21:7:warning: O C++ forbids variable length array ‘c-Wvla
      21 |   int cze];
         |       ^
   Rcppmytest.cpp:22:7:warning: O C++ forbids variable length array ‘a-Wvla
      22 |   int aze];
         |       ^
   Rcppmytest.cpp:35:21:error: valid conversion from ‘int*to ‘int-fpermissive
      35 |   mytest_f(l, m, n, a
         |                     ^
         |                     |
         |                     int*
   Rcppmytest.cpp:6:42:note: initializing argument 4 of ‘void mytest_f(int, int, int, int, int)
       6 |   void mytest_f(int l, int m, int n, int a c);
         |                                      ~~~~^
   Rcppmytest.cpp:35:24:error: valid conversion from ‘int*to ‘int-fpermissive
      35 |   mytest_f(l, m, n, a, c
         |                        ^
         |                        |
         |                        int*
   Rcppmytest.cpp:6:49:note: initializing argument 5 of ‘void mytest_f(int, int, int, int, int)
       6 |   void mytest_f(int l, int m, int n, int a, int c
         |                                             ~~~~^
   Rcppmytest.cpp:37:10:error: valid conversion from ‘int*to ‘int-fpermissive
      37 |   return c
         |          ^
         |          |
         |          int*
   make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:178: Rcppmytest.o] Error 1
   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mytestpackage’
```

My questions would be:

1. How to make it work (Any help and hints would be appreciated)?
2. Should I care about the column-/row-major order difference between R/Fortran and C/C++?

Notes:
The reason I'm using Rcpp is that I tried writing a small init.c file similar to [here](https://github.com/cran/gausscov/blob/master/src/init.c) however, my efforts wasn't successful.

Comment: What is `C/C++`? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the C++ side of your glue, and the good news is that it is simple -- at least to get to a pointer and pass it along.  Here is what I would do:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

extern "C" {
    void mytest_f(int l, int m, int n, int *a, int *c);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector c_mytest_f(Rcpp::IntegerVector a3D) {

    // receives the 3D array
    Rcpp::IntegerVector dim = a3D.attr("dim");

    int l = dim[0],
        m = dim[1],
        n = dim[2];

    Rcpp::IntegerVector c(l*m*n); // vectors are contiguous

    mytest_f(l, m, n, &(a3D[0]), &(c[0]));

    return c;
}
```

The changes are to

- pass vectors `a` and `c` as pointers to double along with the dimension information
- allocate the result vector as another `Rcpp::IntegerVector` which gets you both the allocation and the return object
- pass `a` and `c` *as pointers* by accessing the address of their first element.

Lastly, files like the `init.c` you mention are autowritten for you (at least for the C / C++ part) and as `mytest_f` is not called from R you need to worry about it in there -- the calling is done by the glue code, and Rcpp makes setting up glue fairly easy.

All that said, you may have a problem with row-versus-column order between C (or C++) and Fortran. In the 2d-case you could do what you did here with RcppArmadillo types and transpose, I am not aware of a 'quick' fix for the 3d case though there may be a common trick.

Comment: Thanks, @Dirk for the explained answer. Now, I can compile; however, the R session aborts. I would guess that Fortran does not like the pointers. What if I can pass actual data to Fortran from C++, as a 1D row-major array? The row/col order issue is manageable in Fortran.

Comment: Yes, sorry I was riffing there based on other experience with C-based 'foreign function interfaces' -- a pointer to an atomistic type such as `int` or `double` along with the dimension info you have is common but I don't actually have done much with Fortran in the last little while...   But the other part should help you get your data in and out via Rcpp, you may find basic 'how to call Fortran from C' help elsewhere. Just to check the obvious:  those `int` are standard signed 32bit for Fortran too, right?  You could the same _mechanics_ with `double` aka `real`.  Everybody should agree here.

Comment: Thank you very much. My solution would be C & Fortran without Rcpp and writing my own init.c file. I'm not sure about your question. But table 19.1 from Modern Fortran Book (Metcalf et al) mentions the data types interoperability between C & F.

Comment: Sure.  I find the manual SEXP conversions tedious but _chacun a son gout_ as they say.