# Calculation Error of Calling Fortran code in Rcpp

Tags: r, fortran, rcpp

Recently I am trying to add a Fortran function into an existing R package that contains C++ code and is build under Rcpp package. I have successfully added the Fortran function and build the R package. But when I try to run an example for the R package for different times, each time the function returns a different value, which a bit confusing since the Fortran function I added has no undeterministic parameter or contains self iteration. Also sometimes when I try to run the function, R crashes.

This is a part of the Fortran function that are in the file "src/k2s.f95"

```
    REAL*8 FUNCTION k2(n1,n2,n3,vec1,length1,a1,vec2,length2,a2)
          integer :: n1,n2,n3,length1,length2
          integer, dimension(length1) :: vec1
          double precision :: a1,a2
          double precision, dimension(length2):: vec2
          double precision :: P(n1+2)
    ...
          k2 = -1.0
          IF ((n1<1) .OR. (n2<1) .OR. (length2 .NE. n1+n2-1) .OR. (n3<1) .OR. (n3 > 3)) RETURN
          k2 = -2.0
          IF(MINVAL(vec1).LE.0) RETURN
          IF(SUM(vec1).NE.(n1+n2)) RETURN
          IF(MINVAL(vec2).LE.0) RETURN
    ...
    END FUNCTION K2
```

And I have used this answer [Integrate Fortran, C++ with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396802/integrate-fortran-c-with-r) to construct the package. Therefore I have written the following C++ file under src dictionary. This is the content of C++ file "k2s2.cpp"

```
    #include "Rcpp.h"
    extern "C" {
        double k2_(int *n1, int *n2, int *n3, int vec1[], int *length1, double *a1, double vec2[], int *length2, double *a2);
    }
    
    // [[Rcpp::export]]
    double K2_fortran(int n1, int n2, int n3, Rcpp::IntegerVector vec1, double a1, Rcpp::NumericVector vec2, double a2)
    {
        int length1 = vec1.size();
        int length2 = vec2.size();
        double q = 0;
        pval = k2_(&n1,&n2,&n3,vec1.begin(),&length1,&a1,vec2.begin(),&length2,&a2);
        return q; 
    }
```

I think it should be fine. Then I build the package (with Rcpp automatically generates the file "src/RcppExports.cpp" and "R/RcppExports.R" to link the cpp function `K2_fortran` to R) and load all the functions, then I get the R function `K2_fortran`. And I run the following example.

```
    K2_fortran(120, 150, 1, c(80,70,40,80), 0.1, rep(1,269), 1e-6)
```

And the result is -2. Then I rerun the code for the second time, I got the expected result 0.175. For the third time, I got 1(some other returned value when there is an error). Then I run it again, a fatal error occurs in R and closes the R.

If I reopen it and run this example 4 times again. The result will be again -2, 0.175, 1 and a fatal error. I am not sure what has happened.

Comment: Is this some homework that is going on?  This seems _eerily_ close to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75461176/passing-multidimensional-array-from-r-to-fortran-using-rcpp) asked earlier today.

Comment: Also the comment and links I have to [your (now deleted) question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75450200/add-fortran-subroutines-into-a-r-package-with-c-functions-linked-by-rcpp) may still apply for its pointers to [mixedlang](https://github.com/duckmayr/mixedlang).

Comment: I did try to follow the skeleton of mixedlang. And I managed to make it work. It is just the function causes R crashes.

Comment: If some code crashes, a [mcve] is needed for debugging. There is no other way. Please also take the [tour].